# CSV downloading the object and not actual values Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, routes

I'm not quite sure what I am overlooking when attempting to allow csv download on my Game model and I'm getting a little lost.

On the profile show page I render an index like list of games associated with that user, i.e. their game schedule.

The Profiles Controller-

```
def show
 @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])

 if @user
   @listings = @user.listings
   @games = @user.games
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.csv {send_data @games.to_csv}
   end
   return

   render action: :show
 else
    render file: "public/404", status: 404, formats: [:html]
 end
end
```

Then in the `game.rb` I define the method `to_csv`

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |item|
      csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_name)
    end
  end
end
```

And on the profile show page to download the expected csv game schedule

```
<%= link_to "Download my Schedule", profile_path(format: 'csv')%>
```

I believe this might be my issue lies, but that doesn't quite explain what I get in my csv which is just a game object

file- [image: csv-game-object]

Here is my `routes.rb`

```
  resources :games

  match 'friendships/:friend_id' => 'user_friendships#new', :as => :new_friendship
  match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#show', :as => :dashboard

  root to: "profiles#index"

  get '/players', to: 'profiles#index', as:'players'
  get '/players', to: 'profiles#index', as:'users'
  get '/:id', to: "profiles#show", as: 'profile'
```

The file should be formatted with the column names (location, opponent, time, etc) as the header line and the corresponding lines with their respective values for each instance associated to a user.

Comment: to_csv is a class method and not an instance method, you are calling the method on an instance which explains the odd behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `to_csv` method inside **game** should be re-declared as -

1. passed in the games array which needed to be converted.
2. the param passed to `values_at` is `column_names` not `column_name`.

   ```
   def self.to_csv(games)
     CSV.generate do |csv|
       csv << column_names
       games.each do |item|
         csv << item.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
       end
     end
   end
   ```

and in the controller, the code should be:

```
def show
 @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])

 if @user
   @listings = @user.listings
   @games = @user.games
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.csv {send_data Game.to_csv(@games)}
   end
   return

   render action: :show
 else
    render file: "public/404", status: 404, formats: [:html]
 end
end
```

otherwise, you will output all the games no matter which user you are using.

Comment: This implementation is much more understandable and I reworked it based on your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although cenjongh's answer isn't wrong, let me elaborate on it.

The syntax `Game.to_csv(@games)` goes against Ruby's/Rails' object oriented approach for me.

Since the CSV generation code in your case is totally model independent (you don't make any assumptions of column names, etc.) you could feed this method any array of models, i.e. `Game.to_csv(@shampoos)` which would still work but wouldn't read very well.

Since Rails [scopes the `all` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html) according to the criteria attached to the `ActiveRelation` object, using it in your class method wouldn't result in an output of all the games.

Assuming you're using at least Rails 3.0 the line `@games = @user.games` would give you an `ActiveRelation` object, not an array, meaning you can call `@games.to_csv` (or to make it even clearer `@user.games.to_csv`) directly, which reads what it is, namely converting a list of games, that belong to a user into CSV.

Oh, and I guess this is just testing code, but the `return` shouldn't be there. And the `render` statement should go into the block of `format.html`.